# Вытащить информацию из поля JSON в Postman

Tags: json, postman

Автоматизирую тесты бэка в Postman. В JSON приходит такое поле

```
"message": "[SMS] phone = "", code = 8157"
```

Могу ли я как-то вытащить из этого поля только информацию, связанную с "code", чтобы затем поместить его в environment и использовать уже для других запросов?

Comment: На каком языке пишите?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Пишу на javascript

Comment: Если js, то `value.split(',').pop().split('=').pop().trim()`. Не смотря на две аллокации массива, думаю, это будет быстрее, чем через регулярку

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: а почему у вас в json записаны данные строкой, а не частью json ?

Comment: Не могу знать. Так приходит с бэка. Было бы это отдельными полями, то и вопроса бы не было)